# Символы в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Сталкнулся с psql с символами:
база_данных `-#`
база_данных `'#`
база_данных `=#`
Что это такое?

Comment: А в чем сам вопрос?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов узнать что это такое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это строка приглашения интерактивного интерпретатора PostgreSQL.

`=#` - начало новой команды
`-#` - продолжение предыдущей строки
`'#` - продолжение текста в кавычках
`(#` - продолжение текста в скобках
Сам символ `#` можно заменить на другой в настройках, например на `>`
Выводить или не выводить название БД - тоже настраивается.